# Finding the hole in my custom php script?

Tags: php

Today i received very unpleasant email about that one guy has got all my database users records and also he attached a part of screen shot as a proof with the same exact info as in database.

How would i start to look where is the problem? 
What type of hacking attack is that?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: ask the guy, or show your source to someone competent, or post it somewhere public so we can look at it

Comment: If he emailed you to inform you of this, there's a good chance he's willing to help you isolate the problem. You might, if you can afford it, consider hiring him to perform a security audit.

Comment: Personally, I would notify the users of the security breach, and report the hacker to the authorities. If somebody is honest, he doesn't need to download the database as proof of a vulnerability.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing for security vulnerabilities in web applications: Best practices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351315/testing-for-security-vulnerabilities-in-web-applications-best-practices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn how to discover SQL injection vulnerabilities without looking at the source code, read "[SQL Injection Attacks by Example](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)" and "[SQL Injection Walkthrough](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5DP0N1P76E.html)". To prevent SQL injection, use the [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) driver and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements), whose parameters are invulnerable to injection.

Only scalar values in prepared statements can be converted to parameters. Other parts of syntax (e.g. table & column names, lists, ASC and DESC order specifiers) can't be parameterized. For these, don't pass user input directly into the statement. Instead, use a whitelist:

```
$orderDirs = array('up' => 'ASC', 'down' => 'DESC', '' => '');
if (isset($orderDirs[$_REQUEST['dir']])) {
    $orderDir = $orderDirs[$_REQUEST['dir']];
} else {
    $orderDir = $orderDirs[''];
}
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT foo, bar FROM blag WHERE baz > ? ORDER BY foo $orderDir");
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like SQL injection (most likely by url or form parameters).

There are tools out there that you can use to test your site with, e.g. [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.sourceforge.net/), which can take a while to run.

It's most likely that you are generating queries without sanitizing your url and form variables.  SQL injection can often be found by putting single quotes for certain url or form parameters.

**EDIT**: There is an alternative too, which I saw many years ago, a site was using `fopen`, to allow users to proxy image requests through (to prevent it getting caught by hotlinking scripts), however in the fopen, they didn't check that the request for the URL passed (as a URL variable) was in fact a URL.  From the logs, it was clear what the hacker did to get in:

- pass proxy.php as the url variable (e.g. `/proxy.php?url=proxy.php` ) - this returned the source code for proxy.php. find the included files.
- pass the relative paths for the included files to proxy.php to retrieve their source
- find the one with the database credentials in.
- connect to the DB using a mysql client, and gain access to all the data.

Comment: sqlmap seems to be way to go for some basic testing on sql injections, but im having ahard time to setup it properly

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the site you're referring to is the one in your profile, [pokerbanda](http://www.pokerbanda.com).  I see that you're running wordpress 3.0.1 on it (as reported by a friend's tool, [whatweb](http://www.morningstarsecurity.com/research/whatweb)).

I also notice that there is an SQL injection vulnerability reported for wordpress versions less than 3.0.2, so your application is probably vulnerable; have a look at [secunia's vulnerability report](http://secunia.com/advisories/42431/).

As a first step, I would suggest that you upgrade to the most recent version of wordpress.  You should also join any mailing lists they have for announcing releases and try to stay up to date, especially with any security fixes.

Comment: That's not the website im having troubles with but thanks for pointing out about outdated version.

Comment: No problem; you might want to check out the versions and vulnerabilities for any CMSs or libraries that you're using for the site you are having trouble with anyway.

Answer (score 0):

He could have gotten in by SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like SQL injection. This means that somewhere in your code you're passing unsanitized user input into an SQL query. Something like this:

`$sql = "SELECT field FROM table WHERE field = '" . $_GET['formfield'] . "'";`

In this case, a user could submit your form so that the `formfield` variable contains something like this:

`' OR 1=1;--`

That means the SQL passed to your database becomes:

`SELECT field FROM table WHERE field = '' OR 1=1;--'`

which makes the query match everything in that table, returning everything because `1=1` always returns true. The `--` is to denote an SQL comment, so that the database ignores anything after the injected SQL, namely the closing `'`.

It can get even worse, because you could also inject something like this:

`'; DROP TABLE table; --`

The `';` will close your initial query, then a new query `DROP TABLE table;` will get run, destroying that table if it exists.

Examine your code for anywhere that an SQL query is executed including data you received directly from the user. You should really be using something called "prepared statements" which will take care of these sorts of injections for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you use MySQL. There are several measures you can take RIGHT now to prevent that:
1. Change your username and password to access de database
2. Escape every query you perfom in the site using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). This would help you prevent and SQL injection.

Another suggestion, for the security of your users, is encrypt their passwords using md5(). Keep in mind that many people uses the same password across the net, so be aware of that.

Finally, I would suggest you to learn how to use frameworks for PHP coding (let's say CodeIgniter or PHP). Many of these tools, already have built in features to help you make safe transactions with your database.

Hope it helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably SQL injection.

The easiest way to avoid them is to use escape any user-supplied text in an SQL statement, e.g. using mysql_real_escape_string, pg_escape_string, etc.

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection with public writable folders is the worst combination.

One could easily instruct MySQL to write a PHP file in the public writable folder. That PHP file could simply download a larger PHP file that is a backdoor. From there, they can scan your filesystem for passwords and do whatever they want.

To find the problem:

- look at log files, particularly for SQL statements (insert/select/outfile, etc) as get parameters.
- look for new PHP files in public writable folders

You also need to alert all users that their information has been compromised. If you store their passwords in plain text (a horrible thing to do), then the hacker can start logging in to their PayPal accounts since a lot of people reuse passwords.

Comment: well at least for passwords i use sha1

Comment: Do you use unique salts? If so at least that gives you time to warn users.